# Give two matrices whose column spaces contain the column space of the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
>  & 1\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$ Give two matrices whose column spaces
>   contain $C(B)$, the column space of $B$.

The only matrix I can think of that satisfies this is $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$

As I started typing this, I suppose I could do $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\text{,}$$
but that seems like cheating. Are there any other matrices I could use?

Comment: After all of your recent questions on column spaces, I'd have thought you'd have this one in the bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column space of *any* invertible $4\times 4$ matrix will contain the column space of this matrix.  Why?

Once you've figured out why, try to challenge yourself.  Figure out how many columns you *must* have (hint, it's less than $4$) and then find the conditions that a matrix with that number of columns must have to contain this column space in its own.  Once you know the conditions, it should be easy to construct a few.

IMO, this is the type of question where you'll get more benefit out of playing with it than from getting some answers from us here on math.SE.

Comment: I'm mainly reviewing this for terminology's sake... Statistics doesn't really emphasize the theory as much as the linear algebra class I took 4-5 years ago, but I will definitely be thinking of this question.

Comment: I will be reviewing linear algebra for the sake of learning linear algebra in a few months, but right now, it's more of a *learn some definitions to prepare for the M.S. stats program* situation right now. I don't disagree with you at all, by the way. This book I have seems to be way too computational with its problems and doesn't really focus on interesting results, such as what you've presented to me here.

Comment: It was just a suggestion -- if you don't have the time/ want to spend the effort to learn it right now that's completely fine.  The two matrices in your question work though (being $4\times 4$ invertible matrices) -- so good job.

Answer (score 1):

For instance,

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Some easy choices: $kB$ for any constant $k$ or a copy of $B$ with extra $0$-columns in it. Maybe these count as cheating to you too, though.